# ABS() function in oracle and PostgreSQL showing different result

Tags: postgresql

Converting a code from oracle to postgres,But ABS() function showing different format result. How to get exact format as oracle.

ORACLE

```
SQL> select ABS(0.00) from dual;

         0
SQL> select ABS(-2.05) from dual;

      2.05
SQL> select ABS(2.50) from dual;

       2.5
```

Postgres

```
select abs(0.00)

0.00

select abs(-2.05)

2.05

select abs(2.50)

2.50
```

Comment: I don't see a difference

Comment: I don't see any difference either

Comment: Same value, different presentation. And presentation should be done in a presentation layer, not in a database.

Comment: Oracle does not use the ISO Standard SQL conformance on floating point figures. Oracle only know the NUMBER datatype which a non standard name for DECIMAL/NUMERIC. There is no floating point nor INTs in Oracle... But the SQL standard require FLOAT, DECIMAL and INTs datatype that PG do. It is why you see some differences of representation.... BEWARE, when using COUNT, the returned value is a int and when divided by a INT the results must be an INT, which is not true in ORACLE !

Answer (score 0):

The difference you observe is insignificant and is just caused by a different way to display `numeric` data: PostgreSQL shows as many zeros as the scale of the type decrees.

If you want numbers to appear in a certain format, *always* format them using `to_char()`.

Answer (score 0):

use `::REAL` in postgres

use `::` operator to convert decimal number containing trailing zeros to a number without additional zeros.

example:

```
select abs(2.50)::REAL;
```